# What's the alternative to store a function in a Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### Problem

I have a structure like this:

```
<MenuBar />
<NavigationBar>
  <irrelevant stuff here />
  <ActionButton />
</NavigationBar>
<Router>
  <Route ...>
</Router>
```

And I want the ActionButton in the NavigationBar to do something different depending on what Route is rendered by the Router (a standard ReactRouter Router)

### First thought

My first thought was to save a function on the store and using `mapStateToProps` and `connect`, send that function as a prop to the ActionButton. I would dispatch an action with the function as payload whenever the callback should change.

I'm pretty sure that should work, but I know storing non-serialisable stuff in the store can have negative consequences. In particular it gives problems with persisting and rehydrating the contents of a store, as well as interfering with time-travel debugging. [This link from the docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) talks about it and has a reference to some GitHub issues where that is discussed.[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325195/should-i-store-function-references-in-redux-store) also discuss the issue.

### Question

I've seen many places where people say "you shouldn't do that", but I haven't seen an alternative to storing a function in the store yet. The alternative that I can think of is using props drilling, but I would really like to avoid that pattern.

At this point I don't really need to persist or rehydrate the store, and time-travel debugging is a very nice to have but not a must-have. However, I'd like to avoid sacrificing those things if there's a good alternative.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple options:

- Use a middleware to listen for an `"ACTION_BUTTON_CLICKED"` action, and run different logic based on other values (store state, route, etc).  This could be a custom middleware you've written yourself, or a general-purpose side effects middleware like `redux-saga` or `redux-observable` that lets you respond to dispatched actions.
- Put a predefined action into the store based on other behaviors, and have that action be dispatched when the button is clicked.

I show an example of the predefined action approach in my post [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the state of `react-router` in your redux store. Then when navigation state changes, you can access the current route from within the `NavigationBar` or the `ActionButton`.

You could store logic for deciding what the button does based on the route in the ActionButton or the NavigationBar.