# Redux reload state when class attribute changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I store a Bluetooth class in my Redux store, expecting the state to update when I modify a property of the class.

The class:

```
export default class BluetoothService {
    constructor() {
        this.isConnected = false
        this.deviceID = ""
    }

    connect() {
        this.deviceID = "something"
        this.isConnected = true
    }

    write() {
      someLibrary.write(this.deviceID)
    }
}
```

Here's the reducer:

```
export default function blueoothReducer(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_BLUETOOH:
            return new BluetoothService()
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I pass it to my component, as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        bluetoothService: state.bluetoothService
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile)
```

I dispatch `LOAD_BLUETOOTH` once when my app loads.

#### The actual problem

In my component, I call `this.props.bluetoothService.connect()`, expecting the component to update and re-render because the `isConnected` property has changed - but the component does not get updated.

Any creative ways to make my component re-render when I change an attribute of the bluetooth class?

Comment: i guess your state object is not updated in your reducer hence why `mapStateToProps` does not notice that action

Comment: @messerbill Can you think of any way of having a stateful redux property?

Comment: imho it would be a better approach to set that "bluetooth connected" value in your redux state and enable / disable it by firing a redux action. Maybe you have been developing angular before? Many angular developers wanna make use of that service mechanincs in angular when using react. But this is the wrong way of thinking in react...just use redux and if async actions are needed `sagas`. No need to define any other "services" at all

Comment: The service contains useful methods that can work app-wide without providing any additional arguments because all the info is stored inside the service class. I am thinking maybe I should dispatch an action just to make the store update and then the component will re-render. Kinda hackish.

Comment: I think the problem is in the reducer. Instead of returning an object when the LOAD_BLUETOOH action is called, you return a new instance of the BluetoothService which is a javascript class. This is very unusual as in redux the state is supposed to be a a plain object.
The normal thing to do would be to keep the isConnected state in your reducer and have an action change its status. Then you could connect your components to read just this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reducer is a pure function](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions). Your reducer is impure. You store an object with methods. Moreover, you can call these methods and redux won't know that something was changed.

If you want to use redux you don't have to store `BluetoothService` in the reducer. Just store properties `isConnected` and `deviceID` and make actions `connect` and `write` to change them.

Answer (score 2):

Since the idea of redux is to have a state that is never mutated from the outside, but only overwritten by reducers, I would actually consider setting `isConnected = true` with the `connect()` method as an anti-pattern. Since your `BluetoothService` instance is actually your redux state, you could easily create a reducer that sets `isConnected`:

```
case(CONNECT):
    return {...state, isConnected: true}
```

It is however not recommended to store functions/methods in the state, since it should always be serialisable (which a function isn't), as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325195/should-i-store-function-references-in-redux-store).