# How to store the value of useRef() in redux, when it references an audio tag

Tags: reactjs, redux, html5-audio, use-ref

I am building an audio app, something like Spotify.

In my App.jsx, I create an audioRef and use it to reference to the html audio element:

`const audioRef = useRef()`

`<audio ref={audioRef} />`

I would like to store the audioRef in Redux with redux-toolkit, to make it accessible globally.

I tried doing it like so:

`useEffect(() => { dispatch(setAudioRef(audioRef)); }, []);`

where setAudioRef is:

`setAudioRef(state, action) { state.audioRef = action.payload; },`

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

`A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: 'payload'.`

The audioRef is used by many different components across the app to check play/pause the audio, access time elapsed, duration, etc.

Any tips would be greatly appreicated!!

Comment: You should see [Should I store function references in Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325195/should-i-store-function-references-in-redux-store?rq=1) and [JavaScript: how to serialize a DOM element as a string to be used later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985/javascript-how-to-serialize-a-dom-element-as-a-string-to-be-used-later)

Answer (score 2):

Don't. An audio object isn't *data* or *state*, and it's not serializable, so it doesn't belong in the Redux store:

https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

A better option would be to have a context provider + a `useState` near the root of the component tree, and put it in there.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: @digitalnomad21 I believe this could help https://campedersen.com/react-audio/